# Regex character combinations

Tags: java, regex

Hi i want to form character combinations like

Combination of Alphabets,
    Numerals(2) 
    Special characters(1)
    Minimum 6 characters

I tried using

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,})
```

but i could not able to make the combination as mentioned above.How to do that.?

Comment: You want to create combinations OR to match combinations?

Comment: Some sample input and expected matches would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is basically OK.

You didn't provide the type of regex engine you're using, so unless it's Java or another language that doesn't support verbatim strings, you might need to change `\\d` into `\d`, or that part of the regex will try to match a literal backslash, followed by a `d`.

Also, you should anchor the regex to the start of the string to improve performance. In Java, the `.matches()`  method will do that for you implicitly.

Then, currently your regex requires only one digit, but two ASCII alphabetics (one lowercase, one uppercase). Is that really what you want?

I would have interpreted your requirements like this:

```
if (subjectString.matches("(?=.*\\d.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,}")) {
    // Password matches the criteria
} else {
    // Password doesn't match the criteria
}
```